# Changing the autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, html

I really do like the autocomplete function, but is it possible to change it so it's blank when I press inside of the textbox, and only displays countries when I start type something in?

When I start typing something, like "Alb", and then remove this and click outside of the textbox, then click inside of it again the previous results is still there.

**Code snippet:**

```js
// Sample list of autocomplete options
var countries = [
  "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
  "The Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
  "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi"
];

// Get references to the input field and the dropdown list
var input = document.getElementById("country-name");
var autocompleteList = document.getElementById("suggestion-list");

// Function to display the dropdown list
function showAutocompleteList() {
  autocompleteList.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to hide the dropdown list
function hideAutocompleteList() {
  autocompleteList.style.display = 'none';
}

// Event listener for input field
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var inputValue = input.value;
  autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';

  // Filter and display matching items
  countries.forEach(function(country) {
    if (country.toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue.toLowerCase())) {
      var item = document.createElement("li");
      item.textContent = country;
      item.classList.add("autocomplete-item"); // Add the "autocomplete-item" class
      item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        input.value = country;
        autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';
      });
      item.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        item.classList.add("active"); // Add the "active" class on hover
      });
      item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        item.classList.remove("active"); // Remove the "active" class when not hovering
      });
      autocompleteList.appendChild(item);
    }
  });

  showAutocompleteList(); // Display the list when input changes
});

// Event listener for "keydown" on the input field
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Tab") {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default tab behavior

    // Handle the Tab key behavior for selecting an item
    var activeItem = autocompleteList.querySelector(".autocomplete-item.active");
    if (activeItem) {
      input.value = activeItem.textContent;
      autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';

      // Redirect to the corresponding HTML page
      var countryUrl = 'Countries/' + activeItem.textContent.toLowerCase() + '.html';
      window.location.href = countryUrl;
    }
  }
});

// Event listener for clicking on the list items
autocompleteList.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("autocomplete-item")) {
    // If the clicked element has the "autocomplete-item" class
    input.value = e.target.textContent;
    // Redirect to the corresponding HTML page
    var countryUrl = 'Countries/' + e.target.textContent.toLowerCase() + '.html';
    window.location.href = countryUrl;
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default click behavior
  }
});

// Event listener to close the dropdown when clicking outside of the input field
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target !== autocompleteList && e.target !== input) {
    hideAutocompleteList();
  }
});

// Event listener for clicking inside the input field to display the dropdown
input.addEventListener("click", showAutocompleteList);
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Select a country</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="get-container">
      <input type="text" id="country-name" placeholder="Enter a country" autocomplete="off">
      <div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>

      <div id="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="story-container">
      <div id="generated-text"></div>
      <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: As you have it now this displays your placeholder.  Perhaps update that or elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: When I start typing something, like "Alb", and then remove this and click outside of the textbox, then click inside of it again the previous results is still there.

Comment: Right now it redirects as soon as I click outside

Comment: This and the accepted answer generate invalid HTML.  When I get a few spare moments I will try to create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Added the `focus` event listener to clear the list when input field is clicked.
2. Updated the `showAutocompleteList()` function to only display the list if the input value is not empty.
3. Updated the input's `input` event listener to only filter and display the list if the input has at least one character.
4. Modified the input's `keydown` event listener to check for the length of the input value before displaying the list.

```js
var countries = [
  "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
  "The Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
  "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi"
];

// Get references to the input field and the dropdown list
var input = document.getElementById("country-name");
var autocompleteList = document.getElementById("suggestion-list");

// Function to display the dropdown list
function showAutocompleteList() {
  if (input.value !== '') {
    autocompleteList.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

// Function to hide the dropdown list
function hideAutocompleteList() {
  autocompleteList.style.display = 'none';
}

// Event listener for input field
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var inputValue = input.value;
  autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';

  // Only filter and display the list if there is at least one character
  if (inputValue.length > 0) {
    countries.forEach(function(country) {
      if (country.toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue.toLowerCase())) {
        let item = document.createElement("li");
        item.textContent = country;
        item.classList.add("autocomplete-item"); // Add the "autocomplete-item" class
        item.addEventListener("click", function() {
          input.value = country;
          autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';
        });
        item.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
          item.classList.add("active"); // Add the "active" class on hover
        });
        item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
          item.classList.remove("active"); // Remove the "active" class when not hovering
        });
        autocompleteList.appendChild(item);
      }
    });
    showAutocompleteList(); // Display the list when input changes
  } else {
    hideAutocompleteList(); // Otherwise, hide the list
  }
});

// Event listener for "keydown" on the input field
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Tab") {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default tab behavior

    // Handle the Tab key behavior for selecting an item
    var activeItem = autocompleteList.querySelector(".autocomplete-item.active");
    if (activeItem) {
      input.value = activeItem.textContent;
      autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';

      // Redirect to the corresponding HTML page
      var countryUrl = 'Countries/' + activeItem.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase() + '.html';
      window.location.href = countryUrl;
    }
  }

  // Only display the list if the input has at least one character
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    showAutocompleteList();
  } else {
    hideAutocompleteList(); // Otherwise, hide the list
  }
});

// Event listener for clicking on the list items
autocompleteList.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("autocomplete-item")) {
    // If the clicked element has the "autocomplete-item" class
    input.value = e.target.textContent;
    // Redirect to the corresponding HTML page
    var countryUrl = 'Countries/' + e.target.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase() + '.html';
    window.location.href = countryUrl;
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default click behavior
  }
});

// Event listener to close the dropdown when clicking outside of the input field
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target !== autocompleteList && e.target !== input) {
    hideAutocompleteList();
  }
});

// Event listener for clicking inside the input field to display the dropdown
input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    showAutocompleteList();
  }
});
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Select a country</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="get-container">
      <input type="text" id="country-name" placeholder="Enter a country" autocomplete="off">
      <div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>

      <div id="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="story-container">
      <div id="generated-text"></div>
      <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: And what if I leave like the letter "a" in the textbox then click outside of it. When I then click inside of the textbox I want that list to still show.

Comment: you can modify the input's "focus" event listener to check for the length of the input value before displaying the list

Comment: @PatrikQvarnström updated

Comment: Since you hide on click, you need to change the click event handler to check what you are clicking and NOT hide if the user clicks in the field - as you just did :)

Comment: Ok there's still one issue with this code, how do I make an item like "Burkina Faso" not lead me to this: burkina%20faso.html but instead to: burkina-faso.html?

Comment: can be done via replace, before creating countryUrl var;

Comment: I'm not really familiar with JS, so could you please help me with this? It's the last thing I have to do to get closer to a functioning website I hope.

Comment: @PatrikQvarnström done

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked really well! =)

Comment: Suggest changing your various `var` to reduce hoisting perhaps `var item =`  to `let item =` or if nothing changes it to `const item = `

Comment: @Mark sure thing :)

Comment: This generates invalid HTML - as does the OP's code this derives from.

Answer (score 0):

Changes from original code:

- Changed to append a `<div>` for item since it is invalid to append `<li>` to a div
- Changed to use data attributes for items and not `value` - the value on an `li` can only be a integer and only on `li` in an `ol` ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li
- put the lower case value to avoid doing it on match
- used `.filter()` for the match to array values
- used `const` not `var` on cached values
- used a proper CSS class to and toggle that on the show/hide to simplify that code and follow best practice
- created functions to be called for various actions
- took out hard coded `Country/` and put it as a data attribute on the container and not in code
- moved the event handler from the list generation and used delegated events (see `populateList()` for an updated code for that
- added a `focus` event for the input to show the list
- Minor CSS added to better illustrate visually what was happening including the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on the list items.  Added a border to the actual list just to show what was where (non of this is part of the question answer but illustrates visually what is going on.

Suggestion: rather than removing and adding to the DOM for the list, consider generating them all then showing/hiding using the function I created `showElement(element, shouldHide)` instead, called within the filter portion of the code

```js
// Sample autocomplete options
const countries = [
  "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
  "The Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
  "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi"
];

// cache references
const input = document.getElementById("country-name");
const autocompleteList = document.getElementById("suggestion-list");

function showElement(element, shouldHide) {
  element.classList.toggle('hide-me', !shouldHide);
}

function clearElement(element) {
  element.innerHTML = '';
}

function showValue(element, value) {
  element.value = value;
}

function getUri(el, inputElem) {
  const eTarg = el;
  const isItem = eTarg &&
    eTarg.classList &&
    eTarg.classList.contains("autocomplete-item");
  console.log(eTarg, isItem);
  if (isItem) {
    const myName = eTarg.dataset.linkname;
    inputElem.value = eTarg.textContent;
    const parentContainer = eTarg.closest('.get-container');
    const urlRoot = parentContainer && parentContainer.dataset ? parentContainer.dataset.urlroot : "notfound/";
    const countryUrl = urlRoot + myName + '.html';
    return countryUrl;
  }
  return 'woops';
}

function populateList(listParent, words, filterValue, listTarget) {
  const activeClassName = 'active';
  const filterLower = filterValue.toLowerCase();
  const holder = document.createDocumentFragment();
  words.filter((word) => {
    return word.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterLower);
  }).forEach(function(word) {
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    el.textContent = word;
    el.classList.add("autocomplete-item");
    el.dataset.linkname = word.toLowerCase();
    holder.appendChild(el);
  });
  listParent.appendChild(holder);
}

input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  const inputValue = this.value;
  clearElement(autocompleteList);
  populateList(autocompleteList, countries, inputValue, this);
  showElement(autocompleteList, true);
});

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
  if (ev.key !== "Tab") return;
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent tab to next element (non-standard)
  const activeItem = autocompleteList.querySelector(".autocomplete-item.active");
  if (activeItem) {
    const countryUrl = getUri(activeItem, input);
    showValue(input, activeItem.textContent);
    clearElement(autocompleteList);
    console.log('donothing:', countryUrl);
    // Redirect to the corresponding HTML page
    // window.location.href = countryUrl;
  }
});

autocompleteList.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
  // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation
  const itemClass = "autocomplete-item";
  const activeClassName = 'active';
  const eTarg = event.target;
  const parent = event.currentTarget;
  parent.classList.add("parents-fun");
  const currActive = parent.querySelector(`.${itemClass}.${activeClassName}`);
  if (currActive) {
    //remove from prior item
    currActive.classList.remove(activeClassName);
  }
  if (eTarg && eTarg.classList && eTarg.classList.contains(itemClass)) {
    eTarg.classList.add(activeClassName);
    showValue(input, eTarg.textContent);
  }
}, true);

autocompleteList.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
  // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation
  const itemClass = "autocomplete-item";
  const activeClassName = 'active';
  const eTarg = event.target;
  const parent = event.currentTarget;
  if (!!parent && !!parent.classList) {
    parent.classList.remove("parents-fun");
  }
  if (eTarg && eTarg.classList && eTarg.classList.contains("autocomplete-item")) {
    eTarg.classList.remove(activeClassName);
  }
});

// Event listener for clicking on the list items
autocompleteList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const eTarg = event.target;
  const countryUrl = getUri(eTarg, input);
  console.log('donothing would go to:', countryUrl);
  //window.location.href = countryUrl;
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default click behavior
});

// hide dropdown when clicking outside input
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const shouldShow = (event.target === autocompleteList || event.target === input);
  showElement(autocompleteList, shouldShow);
});

document.getElementById("country-name")
  .addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", {
      'bubbles': true
    }));
  });
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}

.autocomplete-items.parents-fun {
  border: solid #0000FF 1px;
}

.autocomplete-items .autocomplete-item {
  padding: 1px;
}

.autocomplete-items .autocomplete-item.active {
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
  padding: 0px;
}

.country-name:focus {
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
  background-color: #00FF0020;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Select a country</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="get-container" class="get-container" data-urlroot="Countries/">
      <input type="text" id="country-name" class="country-name" placeholder="Enter a country" autocomplete="off" />
      <div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>
      <div id="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="story-container">
      <div id="generated-text"></div>
      <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```